# flutter android app uses-permission - how to find out where they came from

Tags: android, flutter, permissions, apk

When I build the appbundle of my flutter application, I see the following list of permissions in the final bundle manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USB_PERMISSION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

but I didn't ask for these permissions in my manifest.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I tried to look through all the dependencies, but also found nothing. Is there any way to find out where the permissions come from in the flutter application?

My AndroidManifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="myPackage">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:label="MyAppLabel"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:extractNativeLibs="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_notification" />
        <meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/accentBlue" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```